# Threading Bluetooth communication Raspberry pi (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

my problem is, how can i implement threadings to my program, where i have communication BLE with Rpi3.

My program works great, but response is too slow.
Please help with this. Thanks.

BMS_reading:

```
import gatt
import sys
import time
import threading

class AnyDevice(gatt.Device):

    def write(self, characteristic):
        self.response=bytearray()
        self.bms_write_characteristic.write_value(bytes([0xDD,0xA5,0x03,0x00,0xFF,0xFD,0x77]));

    def services_resolved(self):
        super().services_resolved() 
        device_information_service = next(
            s for s in self.services
            if s.uuid == '0000ff00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb')

        self.bms_read_characteristic = next(
            c for c in device_information_service.characteristics
            if c.uuid == '0000ff01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb')
            
        self.bms_write_characteristic = next(
            c for c in device_information_service.characteristics
            if c.uuid == '0000ff02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb')
            
        self.bms_read_characteristic.enable_notifications()
        self.write(self.bms_read_characteristic)

    def characteristic_value_updated(self, characteristic, value):
        self.value=value
        def write(): 
            self.response+=self.value
            if (self.response.endswith(b'w')):
                self.response=self.response[4:]
                self.SoC=int.from_bytes(self.response[19:20], byteorder = 'big')
                self.manager.stop()
        write()

 
#reading loop (I want add threading and read info "SoC")
while True:
    address="A4:C1:38:A0:59:EB"
    manager = gatt.DeviceManager(adapter_name='hci0')
    device = AnyDevice(mac_address=address, manager=manager)
    device.connect()
    manager.run()
    print("Capacity is: "+str(device.SoC)+"%")

TERMINAL <<< Capacity is: 76% 
#long delay which i dont want
<<< Capacity is: 76%
```

I dont know how can i make it.
when i make thread all while loop, the communication does not have time to react and prints bad numbers or errors.

Please help.

--------------------EDITED--PROGRAM--FOR--NOTIFICATION------UPDATE----------

```
import gatt
import json
import sys
#from gi.repository import GLib

manager = gatt.DeviceManager(adapter_name='hci0')
class AnyDevice(gatt.Device):
    def connect_succeeded(self):
        super().connect_succeeded()
        print("[%s] Připojeno" % (self.mac_address))

    def connect_failed(self, error):
        super().connect_failed(error)
        print("[%s] Connection failed: %s" % (self.mac_address, str(error)))

    def disconnect_succeeded(self):
        super().disconnect_succeeded()
        print("[%s] Disconnected" % (self.mac_address))
        self.manager.stop()

    def services_resolved(self):
        super().services_resolved()

        device_information_service = next(
            s for s in self.services
            if s.uuid == '0000ff00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb')

        self.bms_read_characteristic = next(
            c for c in device_information_service.characteristics
            if c.uuid == '0000ff01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb')

        self.bms_write_characteristic = next(
            c for c in device_information_service.characteristics
            if c.uuid == '0000ff02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb')

        print("BMS found")
        self.bms_read_characteristic.enable_notifications()
        

    def characteristic_enable_notifications_succeeded(self, characteristic):
        super().characteristic_enable_notifications_succeeded(characteristic)
        print("BMS request generic data")
        self.response=bytearray()
        self.bms_write_characteristic.write_value(bytes([0xDD,0xA5,0x03,0x00,0xFF,0xFD,0x77]));

    def characteristic_enable_notifications_failed(self, characteristic, error):
        super.characteristic_enable_notifications_failed(characteristic, error)
        print("BMS notification failed:",error)

    def characteristic_value_updated(self, characteristic, value):
        self.response+=value
        if (self.response.endswith(b'w')):
            self.response=self.response[4:]
            temperature= (int.from_bytes(self.response[23+1*2:1*2+25],'big')-2731)/10
            print("Temperature is: "+str(temperature) + " C")
         

    def characteristic_write_value_failed(self, characteristic, error):
        print("BMS write failed:",error)

device = AnyDevice(mac_address="A4:C1:38:A0:59:EB", manager=manager)
device.connect()
manager.run()
```

Terminal print, even if the value changes and the manager is running:

```
>>>BMS found
>>>BMS request generic data
>>>Temperature is: 19 C
#there program get stuck even if value is changing
```

thank you, I edited the program with notifications and as you can see, it supports it.

But I have a problem here that even if the values ​​(temperatures) change and manager in in manager.run (), the terminal will send me only one value and did nothing else even if I heat the device. when I restart the program the value changes again and only one remains. Do I have a code written correctly, please?

Thnak you so much for your time sir.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you are using the [gatt-python](https://github.com/getsenic/gatt-python) library.

The line `manager.run()` is starting the event loop so you do not need to have a while loop in your code.

If the temperature characteristic supports notifications, then [turning them on](https://github.com/getsenic/gatt-python#subscribing-for-characteristic-value-changes) would be the most efficient way of reading the values when they change.

If the device does not have notifications then creating a timed event to read the temperature at the frequency you require would be recommended. The documentation for for [timeout_add_seconds](https://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/glib-functions.html#function-glib--timeout-add-seconds) isn't always the easiest to understand, but the import is:

```py
from gi.repository import GLib
```

Then just before you run the event loop call:

```
GLib.timeout_add_seconds(2, my_callback_to_read_temperature)
```

I expect gi.repository to be installed on the RPi already but if you need the instructions for installing, then they are at: https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#ubuntu-getting-started

Comment: thank you, I edited the program with notifications and as you can see, it supports it.

But I have a problem here that even if the values ​​(temperatures) change and manager in in manager.run (), the terminal will send me only one value and did nothing else even if I heat the device. when I restart the program the value changes again and only one remains. Do I have a code written correctly, please?

Thnak you so much for your time sir.

Comment: What you have done seems to be inline with what the library [example](https://github.com/getsenic/gatt-python/blob/e1b147d54ff199571b6c0b43bdd3a9e1ce03850c/examples/read_firmware_version.py#L19). There are a couple of things you can do to debug this. 1) Use a generic app like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) to ensure temperature notifications are working as expected on your temperature device. 2) Have a print statement before the `if` statement in your `characteristic_value_updated` method so you can see what value is sent